# Including semantic UI to my angular js

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I am new to semantic UI. I am trying to include the built in classes of semantic UI to my code. Semantic folder is containing so many built in classes.

1 . How do I find to which css file, my class is going to be associated?
2.  In some of the examples, I see class names like - div class="ui large blue icon button" . In such cases how do I find these variations like blue,floated?

```
 <html>
    <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../SemanticUI/semantic/packaged/css/semantic.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SemanticUI/semantic/packaged/css/semantic.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SemanticUI/semantic/less/elements/button.less"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="ui labeled icon button">
      Download <i class="download icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ui icon button">
      <i class="download icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ui button">
      Download
    </div>
    <div class="ui facebook button">
      <i class="facebook icon"></i>
      Facebook
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks,
Sabari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the css and the javascript libraries for semantic-ui.
Here try this example:

```
 <html>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.12.0/css/semantic.min.css"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.12.0/javascript/semantic.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="ui labeled icon button">
      Download <i class="download icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ui icon button">
      <i class="download icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ui button">
      Download
    </div>
    <div class="ui facebook button">
      <i class="facebook icon"></i>
      Facebook
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is a jsbin POC: http://jsbin.com/ubiReqa/1/

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
Praney